# Publish nopcommerce to Azure

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce. It's is running fine in Visual Express for the web and I have customized several features.
I tried to publish it to Azure:

- I changed the build for every project in the solution to Release and rebuilt
- I highlighted the Nop.Web (or NopAdmin) project and clicked Publish and followed the steps.

However publish fails. In Azure I see the database and website created. I have searched for how to publish to Azure but could not find an answer.
I am using nopcommerce 3 and Visual Express 2013 for the web. Where can I find a step by step guide on how to publish to Azure?

Comment: the errors say  nop.services.dll ,autofac.dll and nop.framework.dll are not  found  in nop.web project. but i can see them all in \bin

Comment: I found a better host:myAsp.net  supports all versions of nopcommerce and it is one click install

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio
2. Clean and Re-build the entire solution
3. Publish the "Nop.Web" project from Visual Studio

You can publish through FTP or directly from visual studio using web deploy

**a) FTP**

you can published to a local File System then upload the published files through ftp.
How to get FTP credentials for azure?
you go Azure.com - > My Account -> Management portal -> Choose your website -> go Dashboard -> quick glance

[image]

From here you can find the ftp credentials or you can 'Reset your deployment credentials' or 'Download the publish profile' or

For new azure portal 
go portal.azure.com -> browse websites -> navigate to your website -> PROPERTIES 
From here you can find the ftp credentials or you can 'Reset your deployment credentials' or 'Download the publish profile' or

**b) Visual Studio - web deploy**

You can also deploy directly to azure from visual studio. Download or get the deployment credentials from azure using the above way and setup web deploy profile in visual studio
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shahdat! If you don't mind I'll add this info to http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Installing+on+Windows+Azure

Comment: Sure, that would be great! @and.maz

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this: [Hosting nopCommerce on Windows Azure Web Sites with Automatic Source Control Deployment](http://www.pronopcommerce.com/hosting-nopcommerce-on-windows-azure-web-sites-with-automatic-source-control-deployment)

Comment: Can this be done in latest nopCommerce version 3.80 ? , or should we follow latest microsoft articles, For more information, see the source control and continuous integration chapters of the [Building Real-World Cloud Apps with Azure](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/introduction) e-book and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso) post.